# Folder Structure for domain and subdomains

Tags: html, hosting, web-hosting

Hi I have been learning how to design a website and it went ok but i tested it on localhost and everything is working as it should but i have been having some trouble with functionality when i have uploaded my files to my hosting provider Arvixe.

I've been trying to learn  how to structure my website properly in the domain folders but i can't work out how it should be properly organised.

I have a Parent website, and subdomains that need to go together so for example -

```
Parentwebsite.com
Subdomain1.Parentwebsite.com
Subdomain2.Parentwebsite.com
Subdomain3.Parentwebsite.com
```

On my locahost test server i just created the websites individually and put them under the htdocs folder in XAMPP. However the folder structure for the Arvixe hosting is a lot different - it currently looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5w2h.jpg

Am i laying out my folders correctly?

And also if i have PHP scripts for the website are they better suited to go into their own folder inside public html? Or they better suited to go directly into the public html folder?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your web host is using cPanel and it has typical directory structure which is quite different compared to your Local XAMPP environment.

Here's how cPanel stores the website files.

```
/home/cPanel-user/public_html ==> Main domain 
/home/cPanel-user/public_html/addon-domain-directory ==> Addon domain
/home/cPanel-user/public_html/subdomain-directory ==> Sub-domain
```

To make your website accessible via web, upload your web content files to 
/home/cPanel-user/public_html directory.

When you add a addon domain from cPanel, its web files will be stored at;

**/home/cPanel-user/public_html/addon-domain-directory**

When you add subdomain, its web files will be stored at;

**/home/cPanel-user/public_html/subdomain-directory**